# how to backup and restore .db database in iPhone application using iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, restore

i have an application, in which i use SQLite database(.db) to store data. now we want to use iCloud for sync between devices. is there any option to do that.
i found like
use XML file to store and restore it from iCloud.
or use core data for that.

but as i said my app is already developed in SQLite .i don't want to migrate whole db to core data. please provide me any other solution if possible

any help is greatly appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Shraddha, so have you implemented your requirement please let us inform, it would be helpful for many iOS beginners.